# Showing different objects depending on user selection in menu

Tags: javascript, html

I have html code where dropdown menu has several values including "Custom". I would like to have different html content below dropdown menu depending on user selection. If user chooses "Custom" value then I need to show one more dropdown menu and two editboxes and if in any other cases I need to show only one editbox.

As I understand I need to use `onchange()` event and javascript code. Is that right?
Could you please advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are just getting started with this.  Yes, you are probably going to end up using javascript for this.  You need to understand that javascript is used to

1. Modify the DOM (i.e. the html) on the page dynamically
2. Detect events that happen on different elements of the DOM(e.g. a `div` or the `window`).

among other things.

The `change` event is only one event.  Depending on the requirements, you might want to use change, but you might want to show the submenu when the user hovers the pointer over `Custom`.

Be aware that there are probably libraries you can use to show menus with submenus.

If you want to roll your own, you should try the following:

1. Show a div that looks like a popup when the user clicks a button or some area of the screen.
2. Populate the popup with the menu options
3. Detect when the user mouse-over or clicks the 'Custom' option.
4. Display the submenu.

Comment: thank you. I was also thinking about div. Does it mean I need to use two divs? One for another dropdown list and two editboxes and another div with just editbox? Would you please give some code to show what you mean?